# Is there a relationship between the Roman/fascist salute and the gestures of the Roman emperor in the Colloseum?

Tags: ancient-rome, roman-empire, fascism

Last October I went to visit Rome and enjoyed a tour through the Coliseum. Our tour guide told a number of stories about the Coliseum, most of which sounded plausible enough. However, one thing seemed rather weird to me. According to our guide, the Roman/Fascist salute had its origins in the gesture of the Roman emperor to signal that a gladiator was supposed to be killed. He "studied the history of that era extensively" and "had his reasons" for thinking so. At that time I thought I'd look it up later, but I couldn't find anything about the relation between these things.

Is there anything to his story?

Comment: Ref. [Roman salute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roman_salute) as previous research...

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: *He "studied the history of that era extensively"* and thinks that the [Pollice verso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollice_verso) has something to to do with the Roman/Fascist salute? Sounds like he studied the proper interpretation of vauge signals coming from alternative realities.

Comment: You might be interested in this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pollice_verso 
It's an article about what gestures may have been used to signal a victorious fighter to kill or spare the defeated.